# Expandable listview for android with "n" data in ParentView and a single common Childview along with header and timeline

Tags: android, expandablelistview

m doing an project to help fellow farmers on pisciculture and m newbie to android from electronics background.

I m stuck with Expandable ListView, as in below:

Category: Prawns /Price on JAN 1 2014   --                  ((Header / Timeline))

Name: Tiger prawns /SPECIALITIES /IMAGE /PRICE             -- ((ParentVIEW from sqlite))

EditView(opinion)/BUTTON(LIKE)/BUTTON(DISLIKE) --((SINGLE common Childview for Every ParentVIEW))

Where in , 1) I m unable to get "N" data in parentVIEW

2) unable to get the "single common ChildView (no array)" with buttons for all parentVIEW

3) No idea about How to Get "Timeline".

4)All above i want it to achieve with CUSTOM-ADAPTER and POJO class for the ParentVIEW.

I have referred following examples
(
http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/
)

which yielded just "FISH NAME" in parentView and the HEADER with "Category".

I have achieved to get "n" data from sqlite in Regular ListView with Custom Adapter and Pojo Class, Please help me with the Expandable ListView.

Thanks And Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question by following links/libraries

https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

https://github.com/mldeng/pinned-section-listview

Thank You,